# Why is my result empty when using this query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting products and a category that the product belongs too to display on a page. Also I get some data belonging to the product that is in a different table.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT cnt.id as content_id, cnt.title as content_title, cnt.featured, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.catid, cnt.images, cnt.state, cnt.introtext, cat.id as cat_id, cat.title as cat_title, cat.alias as cat_alias,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 4 then f.value end) as prijs,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 5 then f.value end) as prijsoud
FROM snm_fields_values f
JOIN snm_content cnt
ON cnt.id = f.item_id
JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cnt.catid = cat.id
WHERE cnt.catid = '17'
AND cnt.state = 1
GROUP BY f.item_id
```

My problem is, when a categorie doesn't have any articles under it, all results are empty. So on a category page where there are no products belonging to that category, it also doesn't show the category title.

Only when a category has a product (snm_content) under it, then it displays all data.

Above query returns the following:

[image]

There are no products under catid 17.

When I change it to 16 (which does have products) this is my result:

[image]

I would like to get all data that is there, so when a category doesn't have products, I still need the category title.

Why is everything empty when a product doesn't exist?

Comment: Take a look at left and right joins. They will include rows in a parent table when no rows exist in a child table.

Comment: You have used equi join (https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-equi-join.php) which basically returns data fulfilling equal conditions that you mentioned in the where clause. So you need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN to return non equi datas. Please check (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: @SloanThrasher I tried using both, but no matter what I get an empty result back. I've tried both LEFT/RIGHT JOIN and LEFT OUTER/RIGHT OUTER JOIN but no result.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` properly.  It's not even a valid `GROUP BY`.  All those non aggregated columns need to be in `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want outer joins.  I don't fully understand the `GROUP BY`, but this may do what you want:

```
SELECT cnt.id as content_id, cnt.title as content_title, cnt.featured, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.catid, cnt.images, cnt.state, cnt.introtext, cat.id as cat_id, cat.title as cat_title, cat.alias as cat_alias,
       MAX(case when f.field_id = 4 then f.value end) as prijs,
       MAX(case when f.field_id = 5 then f.value end) as prijsoud
FROM snm_categories cat LEFT JOIN
     snm_content cnt
     ON cnt.catid = cat.id AND cnt.state = 1 LEFT JOIN
     snm_fields_values f 
     ON cnt.id = f.item_id 
WHERE cat.id = 17
GROUP BY cnt.id, cnt.title, cnt.featured, cnt.alias, cnt.catid, cnt.images, cnt.state, cnt.introtext, cat.id, cat.title, cat.alias
```

Comment: cat.catid needs to be cnt.catid but when I use that I still get an empty result.

Comment: @twan . . . It should be `cat.id`.